# Can CSS animation be done in place of JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering if this jquery construct can be replaced by pure CSS3 ?

```
$('#visibleRoutes > ul:nth-of-type(1)').hover(function () {
                    $('nav#main-nav > div#visibleRoutes > ul:nth-of-type(2)').animate({ marginLeft: '30%' },500);
                    $('nav#main-nav > div#visibleRoutes > ul:nth-of-type(3)').animate({ marginLeft: '30%' },500);
                }, function () {
                    $('nav#main-nav > div#visibleRoutes > ul:nth-of-type(2)').animate({ marginLeft: '0' }, 800);
                    $('nav#main-nav > div#visibleRoutes > ul:nth-of-type(3)').animate({ marginLeft: '0' }, 800);
                });
```

I tried to play around with

```
#visibleRoutes ul:nth-child(1):hover{
                ul:nth-child(2){
                   margin-left:30%
                     }
            }
```

Obviously didn't work. any css expert opinions?

Comment: CSS is static for most part of it, CSS3 does have few text animation but none is fully implemented. So better stick to what you have :).

Comment: Of course you can, but they won't work in old browsers with no CSS3 support.

Comment: @Alvaro I am fine with just modern browsers with css3 support

Comment: This Fiddle (http://fiddle.jshell.net/Hy7TE/1/) shows an example that might help you although it doesn't match your markup.

Comment: @Kyra Thats very close but the .sub doesnt pull back to its place when i hover on it.. looks like i need some more tricks here...